# How make do bot authentication in discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to do bot which to add the server role to New member by reaction.

Answer (score 0):

Use messageReactionAdd event ([documentation here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd)).

Comment: Hi XENO, welcome to SO! While it might be a good answer, it's better to add relevant parts of an external link as a part of your answer. This makes sure your answer is still valuable when the external link changes in the future.